# ERROR: `Trying to get property of non-object` in PHP upload from AngularJS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, file-upload

## upload File in angularjs + php + mysql

Hy folks,
I did the simple uploading, everything works great but I have a problem with uploading a file and add it in table with other information.

```
app.directive("fileInput", function ($parse) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on("change", function (event) {
                var files = event.target.files;
                $parse(attrs.fileInput).assign($scope, element[0].files);
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
$scope.uploadFile = function () {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        var server_id = $scope.info_mainServerID;
        
        console.log(server_id); // value that I need

        angular.forEach($scope.files, function (file, data) {
            form_data.append('file', file);
            form_data.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
        });


        $http.post('php/upload.php', form_data,
            {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false},
                // data: angular.toJson($scope.info_mainServerID)
                server_id : $scope.info_mainServerID
            })

            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                alertify.notify(response, 'success', 2.5);
            })
            .error(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                alertify.notify(response, 'error', 2.5);
            });
    };
```

and the upload.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$server_id = $data->server_id;

if(count($data) > 0){
    if(!empty($_FILES)){
        $path = '../documents/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)){
            $insertQuery =
                "
                    INSERT INTO tbl_document(server_id,file_name)
                    VALUES ($server_id,'".$_FILES['file']['name']."');
                ";

            if(mysqli_query($connect, $insertQuery)){
                echo 'File uploaded';
            }
            else{
                echo 'File uploaded but not saved';
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connect));
    }
}
```

I can't figure it out where to put data for `server_id`, or why it's sending me error

> Trying to get property of non-object in **upload.php** on line **5**

---

everything works great if I try to add just the file in the tbl_document

```
$insertQuery = " INSERT INTO tbl_document(file_name) VALUES ('".$_FILES['file']['name']."'); ";
```

Comment: To start i would do some dumps, echo $path and/or $insertQuery to make sure everything is as is supposed to. Also check if you are getting $_FILES['file'] as is in "upload.php".

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it!

For everyone whom may be in need:

```
angular.forEach($scope.files, function (file) {
    form_data.append('file', file);
    form_data.append('server_id', $scope.info_mainServerID);
});
```

and upload.php

```
$server_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST["server_id"]);
```

I don't know how safe it is, but it works. I'm open for improvements. 
Thanks!